# Removing background color after click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

my link structure looks like this

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html"><span>home</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

but after clicking on the link shadow comes

i don't want that shadow, i want it to be normal without shadow

[normal look when not clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcPVe.png)

[When clicked shodow comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdpmY.png)

Comment: Can you please share your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could share your css we can give you more accurate answer.
but most likely you can prevent this behaviour using `:focus` or `:visited` pseudo class

it will be something like that

```css
a:visited, a:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```